# Making images cached when received by REST service

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jakarta-ee, web-applications

In jsp I have links - something like  `/showImage?n=999;`

In servlet I recieve image by **rest** so that I get an object `java.io.File`. Next I get from file an array `byte[]` and send it into `OutputStream` of `servlet`.

The above works but images do not cache. Note that in rest server I set `CacheControl` into `ResponseBuilder` with `maxAge` and `private(false)`.

When image was opened in browser (by servlet) there is `responce header`

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:6615
Content-Type:image/jpg
Date:Tue, 03 Jan 2017 10:12:25 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=89
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Is it possible to set that images being cached when received from the `rest` service?

some code from `rest` controller

```
File file = new File(path); 
CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
cc.setMaxAge(86400);
cc.setPrivate(false);
ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok( file );
builder.cacheControl(cc);
builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = flower.jpg");
return builder.build();
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you set the cache control.

Comment: @PaulWasilewski I've updated the topic (see the bottom part).

Comment: Are you checking in the controller whether or not the response is cached yet or not?? Generally, the client is told the caching policy and the server can control letting the client know whether or not the request is in the same state or not since last time it was requested. The client should either be sending an "If-Modified-Since" header or an ETag hash. For a file, it's pretty simple to just use If-modified-since and check when the file was last modified: `File f = new File('flower.jpg') f.lastModified()`